# Как фронтэнду заранее узнать о доступных действиях в бэкенде?

Tags: python, rest, frontend, архитектура, backend

Приложение работает через rest. Интересует: **как фронтэнду заранее можно знать (не делая запрос) доступно ли текущему пользователю действие по некоему эндпоинту?** Т.е. у фронта должна быть возможность сделать проверку на доступ не делая прямой запрос. Кажется, бэк как-то должен сообщать фронту права текущего пользователя.

Если бы в бэкэнде была система управления доступом только через роли, то примерно так по моему мнению оно работало: при логине пользователя можно было бы ему отправить его роли и фротнэнд через документацию по бэкэнд api делал бы у себя проверки.

Но в нашем приложении разграничение доступа по роли не подходит, ибо права пользователей меняются от состояния системы (например, пользователя добавили в группу A, и теперь он может делать записи в блокноте, который доступен только для группы A. Притом, пользователь, например, должен занимать ещё и какую-то определенную должность в своей компании + могут быть ещё и другие проверки). Такая система доступа выглядит как abac.

Мы используем django фреймворк питона и django-rest-framework с ним. Там в контроллерах указываются permission_classes - проверки, при успешном выполнении которых доступ разрешен. Т.е. в рантайме будут проверяться права пользователя на основе проверок в коде.

Первое, что приходит на ум: иметь идентификаторы на каждое действие и, например по сокетам, при изменении системы отправлять пользователям эти идентификаторы. Но так в каждом контролере нужно будет уведомлять всех причастных пользователей об изменении в доступе к конкретным действиям. Выглядит стремно.

Все тот же вопрос: как фронтэнду заранее можно знать (не делая запрос) доступно ли текущему пользователю (в системе с динамическими правами) действие по некоему эндпоинту? Думаю, большинство приложений работает по динамическим разрешениям, и явно уже сформулировано несколько решений.

Comment: Каким образом сейчас фронт узнает, что какой-то объект изменился на бекэнде? Если реализована защита от перезаписи изменений при параллельном редактировании (не знаю что у вас за приложение, но обычно это есть), то это проблема того же порядка. Как фронт знает, что может сохранить объект и что не случится конфликта (т.е. что у него более-менее актуальная версия загружена)?

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать для авторизации jwt и записать токену в claims пользовательские роли, а в код фронта захардкодить соответствие ролей правам. Или не хардкодить, а загружать один раз при загрузке фронта.

Comment: В том и дело, что в процессе работы приложения права пользователей могут меняться.

Comment: Тогда придётся делать дополнительные запросы.

Comment: Прошу присоединиться к нашей беседе в комментарии выше про сокеты) Думаю есть какой-то выход, все-таки

Comment: Сокеты - не панацея. У них есть свои недостатки и они усложнят в вашем случае как код бэка, так и фронта.